# Does sortByKey in Spark invoke a shuffle?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a huge RDD in which I want to sort individual partitions locally. I looked into sortByKey operation, but it is not clear whether it invokes a shuffle or not. (I want to avoid the shuffle)

In [Cloudera blog](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/01/improving-sort-performance-in-apache-spark-its-a-double/) it is mentioned that sortByKey would involve shuffle but from the [javadoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaPairRDD.html#sortByKey()) of sortByKey, it looks like there is no shuffle till collect() is invoked.

Question: Does sortByKey() involve shuffling of data ? If yes, then what would be the best way to sort data in each RDD partition ? If no, then how does collect() makes everything globally sorted ?

Comment: Spark uses lazy evaluation. The transformations themselves don't invoke any operations, until Spark encounters some called an *output transformation*, which materializes the graph and causes execution to start.  If you want to see what `sortByKey` is actually doing, look into [`BlockStoreShuffleReader.read`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/shuffle/BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala#L44) method

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I would note that `sortByKey` is not fully lazy. It will eagerly process input rdd.

Comment: @zero323 Really? I didn't know that. Can you refer to the part in the code that processes input RDDs? All I see is a `ShuffleRDD` being allocated.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Here is the culprit: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/b0f5497e9520575e5082fa8ce8be5569f43abe74/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/OrderedRDDFunctions.scala#L62

Comment: @zero323 Which leads to this? https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/b0f5497e9520575e5082fa8ce8be5569f43abe74/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/Partitioner.scala#L118

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yup.

Comment: @zero323 Thanks for that.

Comment: @zero323 So sortByKey() samples data and determines approximate bounds by shuffling samples ?

Answer (score 2):

It involves a shuffle, but of course this happen only when an action is involved, as collect or take, in your graph of execution. This is because when the result of the sort has to be consumed from other transforms, record with same key has to be directed to the same consumer on the cluster.

Comment: Thanks. So just to confirm, if I don't call collect() after sortByKey and use some transformation like map() or foreachPartition(), it won't trigger a shuffle ? Then, why is shuffled RDD generated after invoking sortByKey?

Comment: It will trigger shuffle anyway at the end because you have to collect it to driver at the end. Lazy means when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Basically sortByKey() is an wide type transformation. Since All the transformation operations are lazy in  nature, shuffling will happen only when u trigger an action (in your case collect()). In general, transformation are like instructions for an operation. Action will use this instructions for its executions. you can also refer DAG for more clear picture.